# Code generator for generating gRPC services with bazel

Tags: java, code-generation

Is there any recommended code generator that automatically generates Java templated code with some dummy protos? The build is preferred to be using bazel. I know the Spring Boot. Wondering if there is other better solutions.

The main idea is that developers can generate (via the code generator) the code for a hello world gRPC service with a single click. Then they can modify the code a bit to achieve what they want.

Comment: Have you searched for "grpc Java bazel"?

Comment: Hi Louis, do you mean something like: https://grpc.io/blog/bazel-rules-protobuf/  or do you mean something else?